# Stored procedure not executing from nodejs post api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, http-post

I wrote a stored procedure that needs to update a column. when I execute it from sql developer it is updating the column. But when I make a put/post call, stored procedure is not getting executed.

I have provided the api call, stored procedure. I couldn't find out why it is not executing from postman or reactjs application. But when executed from sql management studio stored procedure is working fine

this is my api call

```
  console.log(req.params);
  const request = new sql.Request(dbconn);
  request.input("refNo", sql.VarChar, req.params.refNo);
  request.input("itemNo", sql.Int, req.params.itemNO);
  request.input("heatNo", sql.VarChar, req.params.heatNo);
  // request.input("aDate", sql.SmallDateTime, req.params.aDate);
  request.execute("mobile_updateExistingHQuantity", (err, result) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.send(result);
      console.log(res);
    } else {
      res.send(err);
    }
    res.end();
  });
});
```

this is my stored proc:

```
USE [JSULLC_TEST]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[mobile_updateExistingHQuantity]    Script Date: 11/22/2019 9:56:10 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[mobile_updateExistingHQuantity]  @refNo varchar(20), @itemNo varchar(20), @heatNo varchar(20)as
    update pipe_inventory_mstr set qtyinpcs = qtyinpcs+1, remarks= ' '
    where jsuordref = @refNo and
          itemno = @itemNo and
          heat = @heatNo and
          activitytype = 'HEAT RECEIPT'
```

output from postman:

```
{
    "recordsets": [],
    "output": {},
    "rowsAffected": [
        0
    ],
    "returnValue": 0
}
```

console output in node js:

```
ready to do data operations
{ refNo: 'JSU18495', itemNo: '1', heatNo: 'abc1234' }
ServerResponse {
  _events:
   [Object: null prototype] { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  output: [],
  outputEncodings: [],
  outputCallbacks: [],
  outputSize: 0,
  writable: true,
  _last: false,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: true,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
  sendDate: true,
  _removedConnection: false,
  _removedContLen: false,
  _removedTE: false,
  _contentLength: 64,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: true,
  _headerSent: true,
  socket:
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        reading: true,
        onread: [Function: onStreamRead],
        onconnection: null,
        _consumed: true,
        [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular] },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        paused: false,
        emitClose: false,
        autoDestroy: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        end: [Array],
        drain: [Array],
        timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
        data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Array],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 8,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 3,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: false,
        autoDestroy: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      Server {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        headersTimeout: 40000,
        _connectionKey: '6::::5000',
        [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function],
        [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11 },
     _server:
      Server {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        headersTimeout: 40000,
        _connectionKey: '6::::5000',
        [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function],
        [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11 },
     timeout: 120000,
     parser:
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [IncomingMessage],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        _consumed: true,
        onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming],
        parsingHeadersStart: 0,
        [Symbol(isReused)]: false },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: [Circular],
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 91,
     [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
     [Symbol(timeout)]:
      Timeout {
        _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 6374,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(unrefed)]: true,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 92,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 91 },
     [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
     [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 },
  connection:
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        reading: true,
        onread: [Function: onStreamRead],
        onconnection: null,
        _consumed: true,
        [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular] },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        paused: false,
        emitClose: false,
        autoDestroy: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        end: [Array],
        drain: [Array],
        timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
        data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Array],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 8,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 3,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: false,
        autoDestroy: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      Server {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        headersTimeout: 40000,
        _connectionKey: '6::::5000',
        [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function],
        [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11 },
     _server:
      Server {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        headersTimeout: 40000,
        _connectionKey: '6::::5000',
        [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function],
        [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11 },
     timeout: 120000,
     parser:
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [IncomingMessage],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        _consumed: true,
        onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming],
        parsingHeadersStart: 0,
        [Symbol(isReused)]: false },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: [Circular],
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 91,
     [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
     [Symbol(timeout)]:
      Timeout {
        _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 6374,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(unrefed)]: true,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 92,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 91 },
     [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
     [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 },
  _header:
   'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nX-Powered-By: Express\r\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 64\r\nETag: W/"40-GXYa0aw2jP54NDZMxCAdlnMYYoM"\r\nDate: Fri, 22 Nov 2019 16:23:14 GMT\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
  _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
  _sent100: false,
  _expect_continue: false,
  req:
   IncomingMessage {
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: null,
        ended: true,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: false,
        sync: true,
        needReadable: false,
        emittedReadable: true,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        paused: true,
        emitClose: true,
        autoDestroy: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: true,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] { end: [Function: resetHeadersTimeoutOnReqEnd] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     socket:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Server],
        _server: [Server],
        timeout: 120000,
        parser: [HTTPParser],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 91,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]:
         Timeout {
           _called: false,
           _idleTimeout: 120000,
           _idlePrev: [TimersList],
           _idleNext: [TimersList],
           _idleStart: 6374,
           _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
           _timerArgs: undefined,
           _repeat: null,
           _destroyed: false,
           [Symbol(unrefed)]: true,
           [Symbol(asyncId)]: 92,
           [Symbol(triggerId)]: 91 },
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 },
     connection:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Server],
        _server: [Server],
        timeout: 120000,
        parser: [HTTPParser],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 91,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]:
         Timeout {
           _called: false,
           _idleTimeout: 120000,
           _idlePrev: [TimersList],
           _idleNext: [TimersList],
           _idleStart: 6374,
           _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
           _timerArgs: undefined,
           _repeat: null,
           _destroyed: false,
           [Symbol(unrefed)]: true,
           [Symbol(asyncId)]: 92,
           [Symbol(triggerId)]: 91 },
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 },
     httpVersionMajor: 1,
     httpVersionMinor: 1,
     httpVersion: '1.1',
     complete: true,
     headers:
      { host: 'localhost:5000',
        connection: 'keep-alive',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        origin: 'chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop',     
        'user-agent':
         'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
        'postman-token': '801f1fc7-ba0b-80a5-5c6c-dd5205cadeb3',
        accept: '*/*',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9' },
     rawHeaders:
      [ 'Host',
        'localhost:5000',
        'Connection',
        'keep-alive',
        'Cache-Control',
        'no-cache',
        'Origin',
        'chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop',
        'User-Agent',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
        'Postman-Token',
        '801f1fc7-ba0b-80a5-5c6c-dd5205cadeb3',
        'Accept',
        '*/*',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site',
        'cross-site',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode',
        'cors',
        'Accept-Encoding',
        'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language',
        'en-US,en;q=0.9' ],
     trailers: {},
     rawTrailers: [],
     aborted: false,
     upgrade: false,
     url: '/updateHeatInfo/JSU18495/1/abc1234',
     method: 'PATCH',
     statusCode: null,
     statusMessage: null,
     client:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Server],
        _server: [Server],
        timeout: 120000,
        parser: [HTTPParser],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 91,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]:
         Timeout {
           _called: false,
           _idleTimeout: 120000,
           _idlePrev: [TimersList],
           _idleNext: [TimersList],
           _idleStart: 6374,
           _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
           _timerArgs: undefined,
           _repeat: null,
           _destroyed: false,
           [Symbol(unrefed)]: true,
           [Symbol(asyncId)]: 92,
           [Symbol(triggerId)]: 91 },
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 },
     _consuming: false,
     _dumped: false,
     next: [Function: next],
     baseUrl: '',
     originalUrl: '/updateHeatInfo/JSU18495/1/abc1234',
     _parsedUrl:
      Url {
        protocol: null,
        slashes: null,
        auth: null,
        host: null,
        port: null,
        hostname: null,
        hash: null,
        search: null,
        query: null,
        pathname: '/updateHeatInfo/JSU18495/1/abc1234',
        path: '/updateHeatInfo/JSU18495/1/abc1234',
        href: '/updateHeatInfo/JSU18495/1/abc1234',
        _raw: '/updateHeatInfo/JSU18495/1/abc1234' },
     params: { refNo: 'JSU18495', itemNo: '1', heatNo: 'abc1234' },        
     query: {},
     res: [Circular],
     route:
      Route {
        path: '/updateHeatInfo/:refNo/:itemNo/:heatNo',
        stack: [Array],
        methods: [Object] },
     body: {} },
  locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
  statusMessage: 'OK',
  statusCode: 200,
  [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
  [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]:
   [Object: null prototype] {
     'x-powered-by': [ 'X-Powered-By', 'Express' ],
     'content-type': [ 'Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ],     'content-length': [ 'Content-Length', '64' ],
     etag: [ 'ETag', 'W/"40-GXYa0aw2jP54NDZMxCAdlnMYYoM"' ] } }
```

Comment: @itemNo is defined as varchar on your proc but sql.Int in your parameter list.

Comment: I changed it to Int type, But not working.

Comment: The problem I'm getting is with the smalldatetime. I'm getting the input from the UI but stored procedure is not executing